# Spring Data Redis SET command supports EX and NX

Tags: spring, redis

Do Spring Data Redis support SET command with [Options](https://redis.io/commands/set#options)

My use case:

127.0.0.1:6379> set lock.foo RUNNING NX EX 20

Then check if Redis return value OK or (nil)

Answer (score 1):

Use `RedisTemplate#execute(RedisCallback<T>` method, demo:

```
@Autowired
private RedisTemplate redisTemplate;

public void test() {
  String redisKey = "lock.foo";
  String value = "RUNNING";
  long expire = 20L;
  Boolean result = (Boolean) redisTemplate.execute((RedisCallback<Boolean>) connection -> {
    byte[] redisKeyBytes = redisTemplate.getKeySerializer().serialize(redisKey);
    byte[] valueBytes = redisTemplate.getValueSerializer().serialize(value);
    Expiration expiration = Expiration.from(expire, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return connection.set(redisKeyBytes, valueBytes, expiration, RedisStringCommands.SetOption.SET_IF_ABSENT);
  });
  System.out.println("result = " + result);
}
```

RedisTemplate config:

```
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {
  @Bean
  public RedisSerializer<String> keySerializer() {
    return new StringRedisSerializer();
  }
  @Bean
  public RedisSerializer<Object> valueSerializer() {
    return new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer();
  }
  @Bean
  public RedisTemplate redisTemplate(RedisTemplate redisTemplate, RedisSerializer keySerializer, RedisSerializer valueSerializer) {
    //set key serializer
    redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(keySerializer);
    redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(keySerializer);
    //set value serializer
    redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(valueSerializer);
    redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(valueSerializer);
    return redisTemplate;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot see any Spring template value operations solutions, so I did a 'native' execute on the connection org.springframework.data.redis.connection.StringRedisConnection#execute(java.lang.String, java.lang.String...)
Then it is up to me to take care of processing of arguments and the result.